# LazyInitializationException with Hibernate 4.1, Spring 3.1 and JSF 1.2 (Myfaces)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping, lazy-initialization

I have a webapp using Hibernate 4.1 and Spring 3.1 and JSF 1.2 (myFaces).

I have this "LazyInitializationException" each time I try to access one of my pages

```java
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
at £org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:149)
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:195)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)
at foo.data.bo.implementations.EOServiceType_$$_javassist_10.getTechKey(EOServiceType_$$_javassist_10.java)
at foo.converter.EOServiceTypeConverter.getAsString(EOServiceTypeConverter.java:36)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.RendererUtils.getConvertedStringValue(RendererUtils.java:648)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.getSubmittedOrSelectedValuesAsSet(HtmlRendererUtils.java:362)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.internalRenderSelect(HtmlRendererUtils.java:337)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.renderMenu(HtmlRendererUtils.java:288)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlMenuRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlMenuRendererBase.java:57)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.ext.HtmlMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlMenuRenderer.java:70)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:649)
... 50 more
```

I think I missunderstood something because I don't know How to give the "session" to my classes.

For info, here are some of my configuration files :

spring-config.xml:

```xml
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="foo" />

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
        <ref bean="oracleNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<alias name="jndiDataSource" alias="dataSource" />

<bean name="oracleNamingStrategy"
      class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy">
</bean>

<bean name="jndiDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName">
        <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/fooDS</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My java class EOServiceType

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="EOSERVICETYPE")
public class EOServiceType implements IEOServiceType {

@Id
@Column(name="EOSERVICETYPE_ID")
private long techKey; 

@Column(name="H_PROPERTY")
private String property;

@Column(name="H_DESCRIPTION")
private String description;

//... + all getters and setters
}
```

My DAO implementation for Hibernate EOServiceTypeDaoHibernateImpl

```java
@Repository("eOServiceTypeDao")
public class EOServiceTypeDaoHibernateImpl implements IEOServiceTypeDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void save(IEOServiceType serviceType) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(serviceType);
}

public void update(IEOServiceType serviceType) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(serviceType);
}

    //... and some other CRUD operations...
}
```

My POJO Service implementation for Hibernate EOWebStaffServicesImpl

```java
@Service
public class EOWebStaffServicesImpl implements IEOWebStaffServices {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

//...

@Autowired
private IEOServiceTypeDao eoServiceTypeDao;

    public void saveOrUpdateEOServiceType(IEOServiceType eoServiceType) {
    try {
        eoServiceTypeDao.saveOrUpdate(eoServiceType);
    } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        DuplicateKeyException exception= new DuplicateKeyException("Duplicate business key for " + eoServiceType,e);
        throw exception;
    }
}
    public void deleteEOServiceType(IEOServiceType eoServiceType) {
    eoServiceTypeDao.delete(eoServiceType);
}
```

My Hibernate Config file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.mapping.precedence">hbm, class</property>    
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
<property name="jdbc.batch_size">20</property>

    <mapping class="foo.data.bo.implementations.EOServiceType"/>
    <!-- ... and other mappings -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Does any body have a tip to help me ? I read some articles and post but did not really find a solution to my problem.

Best regards,

Kamran

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of problem several weeks ago. I obviously forgot to *annotate* my method which is interacting with **Hibernate**.

I recommend you the

```
@Transactional
```

annotation. It should fix your problem.

Otherwise here is the related **Hibernate** documentation:
[Sessions and Transactions](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions)

Comment: Wow, I had the exact problem. @Transactional solved the problem. Upvoted

Comment: Dear Adam, thanks for your answer.
My Services are already annotated with '@transactionnal' in the class level.
But my problem is not when using service but when I directly use the 'EOServiceType'. I'm going to edit my post and add also my DAO and Service

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you don't use transactions in your DAO classes. Hibernate will not work with Spring outside of the transaction. You can define declarative transactions with Spring (annotate necessary classes with @Transactional annotation). Here is a link to [Spring reference documentation about Transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html).

Also you should inject SessionFactory to your bean before using it:

```
@autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

Comment: Dear Dimas, thanks for your help.
I have already the sessionFactory injected in my DAO. (I'm going to add my DAO and Service to the post)

Comment: I saw your edition. I think the problem is that you have to use @Transactional annotation on your DAO class too. Not only in service class.

Comment: And by the way, post your hibernate config too.

Comment: I added the hibernate config file.
In the mean time I addes @Transactional at my DAO (at the class level and not method level). But I have still the problem.
I also added it to my "mapping" bean EOServiceType (just for fun) but no more good result :-(

Answer (score 0):

What are you planing to archive with the `SessionFactory` in your service class?

Anyway, i think the problem is that you are trying to access a detached object with lazy properties. (That's usually the case when you see that exception)

Is that all the code there is of your POJOs?

Comment: Dear ortang, It's exactly what you are saying: I'm trying to access a detached object that is lazy. For the POJO I removed some other method. I was just to show how it looks like (600 lines :-p )